# The meaning of "doubles" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> This New Crib Ad from IKEA Actually Doubles as a Pregnancy Test — Like, for Real

The sentence is came from an [article](https://www.babble.com/entertainment/ikea-crib-ad-pregnancy-test/), I have no idea what does the word "doubles" mean there.

Comment: It means that it serves two purposes.

Comment: Compare: *This sofa can **double as** a bed.*

Answer (score 1):

Doubles in this context basically just means that something serves two purposes/functions at the same time.

For example if you have a couch that could be converted into a bed, that couch **DOUBLES** as a bed. If you have a pen, that turns into a knife, the pen **DOUBLES** as a knife.

The ad you are talking about "doubles" because it has dual function as an ad and also a pregnancy test at the same time.

This meaning comes from the meaning of double, meaning a pair of things.